# Using streamreader in C# to save text between <h1></h1> tags in a string

Tags: c#, text-files, streamreader

I am using streamreader in C# and my goal is to read a text file with it and it must filter out text between the tags (like `<Test> </Test>`  or `<Name> </Name>` ) 
And get the name of the tag like ( Test or Name) then save it to a string with the tag name for use later.
I have searched the internet for a few days now but cant find anything, and i dont have much experience with C# but hope there is some one who can help me.
The file itself is a .txt file

here is the code i have until now :

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\testfile.txt"))
            {

                String line;
                // Read line by line
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);

                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
```

expected output is for example a string with name = everything between the name tag in plain text then test = everyting between the test tags in plain text.
sorry for my bad english but i hope there is some one who can helpe me.

Comment: Your text file seems to be xml or html

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: It is a custom made text file(*.txt) with custom made tags

Comment: Then find a custom way to solve your problem

Comment: The expeected output wil be a string with variables inside like name = al text between the name tags and test = al text between test tags etc.

Comment: More details about the file to be parsed need to be provided before anyone can provide a definitive answer to this question. Is it HTML, well-formed XML, or a custom file format. Also, does the output need to be provided in a particular order? And what kind of output do you expect in the case of nested tags?

Comment: Order does not matter and it is a .txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XmlDocument

```
        XmlDocument Info_Document = new XmlDocument();
        Info_Document.Load(@"D:\saraxml.txt");
        XmlNodeList xmlnodelist = Info_Document.GetElementsByTagName("Name");//finding all nodes called "Name"
            foreach (XmlNode c in xmlnodelist)
            {
               string _name=c.InnerText;
            }
```

---

for this file :

```
<test>
<Name> h0</Name>

<Name> h1</Name>

<Name> h2</Name>

<Name> h3</Name>

<Name> h4</Name>

<Name> h5</Name>
</test>
```

---

I got:

h0

h1

h2

h3

h4

h5

Comment: Gonna try that one out thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use regex to filter the text:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

One example is available here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Answer (score 0):

If the file is HTML, you can use the [HTML Agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)  to parse the file, and then query the results by tag name. This is to be preferred to regular expressions because it deals with all the complexities much better, for example, nested tags, poorly constructed html, etc. [Attempting to parse HTML with regular expressions may lead to insanity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1158522).

If it is pure XML, then you can use [XMLDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) in a similar way.

Otherwise, you will need to write a custom parser which is a much more complicated and time consuming enterprise.

If your file complies to a regular grammar, you could build a recursive descent parser.